# Remove brackets from array in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have an array that looks like this:

```
myArray = [[],[],[],[],['test', 'hello'], [], [], [['one', 'two'], ['three','four']], [], ['five']]
```

I need to remove all these empty objects and more unnecessary brack so my array look like:

```
['test','hello','one','two','three','four','five']
```

I tried the following:

```
myArray.removeAll(['[]'] as Object[])
```

My array then return 'false'. Any ideas how I could remove all the uncessary bracket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `myArray.flatten()` to get your expected result

Comment: Perfect, thank you